# Input field outside of div in firefox - Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Getting some odd behavior with a single input field on my login form that only happens in firefox...in chrome it's completely fine. The code is no different than any other input field in the forms on the page but this one is choosing to appear outside of the form div and will not allow you to type in it, also looks like it has a 0% length or atleast the smallest length possible. I'm using bootstrap for the field/form css.

An html snippet of the form (id: email_login is causing the issue):

```html
<form action="process_login.php" name="login_form" method="post" id="login_form" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
  <div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
    <input id="email_login" type="text" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" />
  </div>
  <div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
    <input id="password_login" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
  </div>
  <div style="margin-top:10px" class="form-group">
    <!-- Button -->
    <div class="col-sm-12 controls">
      <input onclick="formhash(this.form, this.form.password);" value="Login" id="btn-login" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" />
      <i class="icon-hand-right"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Heres an image of what's going on
[image: input field]

Thanks in advance...will be happy to provide further info. I didn't include the css as it's just the standard bootstrap classes with no modifications.

EDIT:

I managed to fix this issue by modifying the `.input-group` class in bootstrap from `display:table` to `display:inline-table`.

This did not affect any other forms on my website, but managed to fix the display issue in firefox.

So consider it solved in my case.

Comment: What is the version of boots-trap that you use? I have made [**This DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/riyuriwesa/1/) for you and it works fine!

Comment: I am using the CDN link: https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css. I will check my other css sheets and see if I have anything affecting the inputs.